# How to make sure a user can only delete his own records using Laravel

Tags: laravel, delete-row

How to make sure a user can only delete his own records.

Here how i am deleting a post with the following url.

> http://example.com/dashboard/sessions/delete/{id}

Now user can also pass any post id here and then record will be deleted for that id regardless if the post does not belong to user.
How can i overcome this issue using Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to [use policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#creating-policies) for this purpose

> Policies are classes that organize authorization logic around a particular model or resource. For example, if your application is a blog, you may have a `Post` model and a corresponding `PostPolicy` to authorize user actions such as `creating` or `updating` posts.

If for some reason you don't want to use policies, you can check user manually:

```
if (auth()->check && auth()->user()->id === $post->user_id) {
    // Delete post.
}
```

Comment: What if I'm getting multiple ids to delete, then how can I make use of policies to delete only those ids which belongs to user and not the remaining ones